# Connect Spring Boot with MongoDB Atlas Exception

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I try to setup a free remote MongoDB Atlas Database with my Spring-boot Application. I registered at cloud.mongodb.com and created a Database named "PetziCluster". In Network Access and Database Access are the user "admin" with Password and Network Access from everywhere (0.0.0.0).

The Spring Boot Application has a User Class, a UserController and a User Repository and following setup:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.petziferum</groupId>
    <artifactId>Petziferums-Microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservice</name>
    <description>Petziferum Backend for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://admin:password@petzicluster.s13yq.mongodb.net/PetziCluster?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

When i start the Application ther is following Log showing in the Terminal:

```
2022-01-23 12:40:26.311  INFO 1776 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-01-23 12:40:26.311  INFO 1776 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 987 ms
2022-01-23 12:40:26.473  INFO 1776 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvHost=petzicluster.s13yq.mongodb.net, mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', requiredReplicaSetName='atlas-5kxugo-shard-0'}
2022-01-23 12:40:26.492  INFO 1776 --- [3yq.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server petzicluster-shard-00-02.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2022-01-23 12:40:26.510  INFO 1776 --- [3yq.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server petzicluster-shard-00-01.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2022-01-23 12:40:26.511  INFO 1776 --- [3yq.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server petzicluster-shard-00-00.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2022-01-23 12:40:26.584  INFO 1776 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-01-23 12:40:26.717  INFO 1776 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server petzicluster-shard-00-02.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:689) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:560) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:386) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:335) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(SSLExtensions.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(CertificateRequest.java:819) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(CertificateRequest.java:923) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1462) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1370) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:437) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:878) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1240) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:557) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2022-01-23 12:40:26.718  INFO 1776 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server petzicluster-shard-00-00.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:689) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:560) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:386) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:335) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(SSLExtensions.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(CertificateRequest.java:819) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(CertificateRequest.java:923) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1462) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1370) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:437) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:878) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1240) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:557) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2022-01-23 12:40:26.719  INFO 1776 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server petzicluster-shard-00-01.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:689) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:560) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:386) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:335) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(SSLExtensions.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(CertificateRequest.java:819) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(CertificateRequest.java:923) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1462) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1370) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:437) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:878) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1240) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:557) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2022-01-23 12:40:27.171  INFO 1776 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-01-23 12:40:27.198  INFO 1776 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path ''
2022-01-23 12:40:27.210  INFO 1776 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.m.MicroserviceApplication            : Started MicroserviceApplication in 2.198 seconds (JVM running for 2.64)
2022-01-23 12:40:27.739  INFO 1776 --- [(3)-192.168.1.2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-23 12:40:27.739  INFO 1776 --- [(3)-192.168.1.2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-23 12:40:27.740  INFO 1776 --- [(3)-192.168.1.2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-01-23 12:40:27.748  INFO 1776 --- [(2)-192.168.1.2] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@5f283983 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=petzicluster-shard-00-01.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request}}, ServerDescription{address=petzicluster-shard-00-00.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request}}, ServerDescription{address=petzicluster-shard-00-02.s13yq.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

And there is no Connection to my MongoDB Database possible. The thing is, with MongoDB Compass I can access the Database but not here with Spring boot.

Does anyone have a explanation what I can do to get a Connection to my MongoDB?

I already tryed other Solutions like excluding MongoConfiguration.class in @SpringApplication but it doesent worked.

Comment: what is the version of java you ar using?

Comment: I'm using Java 14

Comment: I usually have this issue, what i do is, i change to open-jdk. But I use java 8

Comment: I created a new Project and it works now. So I can't figure out whats the Problem in the other Project.